# Bash: store replaced substrings

Tags: python, bash, replace, awk, sed

I am processing text files by bash script through a long pipeline, and on one step it is needed to:

- remove some regexp-matching substrings
- write them to file
- and proceed with the rest of the text.

I can use anything that can be used in pipeline. What is the simplest/fastest way?

**Update:**
Example:

`echo -e " apple pears banana \n kiwi ananas cocoa" | magic_script " [ab][a-z]+" removed.txt | cat`

Output:

`pears
 kiwi  cocoa`

removed.txt:

`apple
 banana
 ananas`

What should be in place of `magic_script " [ab][a-z]+" removed.txt` ? It should work with any text and any regexp.

**Update2:**

For other example, if regexp is /a.{2,3}/ :

Output: is like result of `sed -E "s/a.{2,3}//g`

`e peba 
 kiwi ocoa`

removed.txt:  is like result of `grep -Eo "a.{2,3}"`

`appl
ars 
anan
anan
as c`

Comment: have you tried anything, what is input and expected output??

Comment: No, I did not. It is like `cat file | sed -E "s/regexp//g" | grep blahblah`, but the problem is I need to write replaced matches to file, so I guess I should use something else instead of sed.

Comment: Take a look at sed's `w` command to write the current pattern space to a file.

Comment: as far as I understand, w writes out the whole pattern space, and I really don't get how to combine it with s/// to write substituted substrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sort of possible to do this with sed, but since the regex and filename are not fixed and sed doesn't handle shell variables well, awk is the better tool for the job. The awk code we want to run might look like this:

```
{
  head = ""
  tail = $0

  while(match(tail, re)) {                     # while there's a match in the
                                               # part of the line we haven't
                                               # yet inspected
    print substr(tail, RSTART, RLENGTH) > file # print the match to the
                                               # file
    head = head substr(tail, 1, RSTART - 1)    # split off the parts before
    tail = substr(tail, RSTART + RLENGTH)      # and after the match
  }
  print head tail                              # print what's left in the end
}
```

with suitable parameters `re` and `file`. **Thanks to @EdMorton** who pointed out a problem with the original code and suggested this amendment.

To make this callable the way you put it in the question, let's put a little shell boilerplate around it:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 regex filename"
    exit 1
fi

awk -v re="$1" -v file="$2" '
{
  head = ""
  tail = $0

  while(match(tail, re)) {
    print substr(tail, RSTART, RLENGTH) > file
    head = head substr(tail, 1, RSTART - 1)
    tail = substr(tail, RSTART + RLENGTH)
  }
  print head tail
}'
```

Put that in a file `magic_script`, `chmod +x` it, and there you have it. You can, of course, also call awk directly as

```
awk -v re=' [ab][a-z]+' -v file=removed.txt '{ head = ""; tail = $0; while(match(tail, re)) { print substr(tail, RSTART, RLENGTH) > file; head = head substr(tail, 1, RSTART - 1); tail = substr(tail, RSTART + RLENGTH); } print head tail }'
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it can create regexp matches that didn't exist before you started carving up and recombining the record so then you can't test the whole record again. For example if you want to find all `ab`s in a file and you start out with `aabb` then there's initially one `ab` but after you remove it with the `sub()` the first and last chars get pushed together and suddenly a new `ab` appears. You need to skip the part of the record you've already processed on every call to match().

Comment: @EdMorton Yeees...that's a good point. It should be easy to handle though, just by remembering where the last match was and only handling new ones if they appear after that place. I edited something in for it.

Comment: idk if that'll work or not. My gut says it won't but I can't be bothered to think about scenarios. I usually use `head=""; tail=$0; while (match(tail,/re/)) { do stuff with substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH); head=head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1); tail=substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH) } print head tail`

Comment: If we only accept matches that start after the place where the last match appeared (and ended, since we removed the match), then it doesn't contain anything of the head part. It comes to the same thing.

Comment: I took another look and it won't work. Imagine what it would do with `aabbab` - on the 2nd pass it will find the created `ab` so the match() return will be less than `n` even though a 2nd `ab` does exist later in the record.

Comment: Ah, hold on. It might stop prematurely. it won't accept and remove the newly created match, but it won't remove those that come after it. Yeah, I'll need to fix that again. A minute.

Comment: @EdMorton In your example, the first match would be found at `RSTART = 2`, and the created at `RSTART = 1`, so it wouldn't be accepted, but the last `ab` in the line would not be removed. Anyway, I ended up just using your approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

AWK may be used for this purpose.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html
which contains the following conceptual example:

```
$ awk '{ print $2 > "phone-list"
>        print $1 > "name-list" }' mail-list
$ cat phone-list
-| 555-5553
-| 555-3412
…
$ cat name-list
-| Amelia
-| Anthony
…
```

where mail-list is filled with two columns of information: the first column containing the names, and the second containing the phone numbers.

See the `match(string,regex)` function (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-47) for capturing regular expressions, keeping in mind that $0 designates the entire line read in. This function returns RSTART and RLENGTH, which can be used with the `substr(string,position,length)` (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-43) function to return the matched pattern (where string=$0 if you're searching by line).

A great introduction to AWK is here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html
...may look long but worth the investment.

**Update**

If you're actually dealing with multiple lines containing fields of information, and you don't particularly care whether the items found are printed in the same columnar form, then the following would work:

```
echo -e " apple pears banana \n kiwi ananas cocoa\n pork" | 
awk '{
  #printf "\n"
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    i=match($j,/[ab][a-z]+/)
    if(i>0){
      print $j > "removed.txt"
    }else{
      printf $j " "
    }
  }
}'
```

If you do care about retaining the columnar form, then you could use the `printf` function as above commented out with a little massaging to get it just right (and replace second `print` with `printf $j " "`). Since AWK deals in fields, though, the method presented above would cause problems if you had multiple instances of the pattern in a single field (i.e. without a delimiter between) that you wanted to capture.

**Update 2**

Here's a better solution that will ensure all matches are found and is irrespective of fields:

```
echo -e " apple pears banana \n kiwi ananas cocoa" |
awk '
BEGIN {
  regex="a.{2,3}";
}
{
  ibeg=1;
  imat=match(substr($0,ibeg),regex);
  after=$0;
  while (imat) {
    before = substr($0,ibeg,RSTART-1);
    pattern = substr($0,ibeg+RSTART-1,RLENGTH);
    after = substr($0,ibeg+RSTART+RLENGTH-1);
    printf before;
    print pattern >"removed.txt";
    ibeg=ibeg+RSTART+RLENGTH-1;
    imat=match(substr($0,ibeg),regex);
  }
  print after;
}
'
```

Output:

```
e peba
kiwi ocoa
```

Removed:

```
$ cat removed.txt
appl
ars
anan
anan
as c
```

Comment: Thank you so mush for you suggestion. Sorry, it appears my example was horribly misleading (may be it was better without one). There are no any "fields" in my data. Description was complete, it can be any regexp-matching substrings.

Comment: @marlett No problem. I would personally still use AWK for this, although there may be other tools. You would just walk through each line ($0) with the `match` and `substr` functions since `match` returns the starting column (character column, not field column) and length (in characters) of the first instance found. If you keep track of the first and last column of matched instances, then you just walk through to the end of the line with substr($0,ipreviousend,iremaininglengthofline).

Comment: @marlett The solution above produces the same result required by your update2 when regex is replaced with your example regex.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that keeps the lines intact other than what was removed:

```
$ echo -e "apple pears banana \n kiwi ananas cocoa" \
| awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) { if ($i ~ /^[ab][a-z]+/) { print $i > "removed.txt"; $i=""}} print }'
 pears 
kiwi  cocoa

$ cat removed.txt 
apple
banana
ananas
```

Comment: Thank you so mush for you solution. Unfortunately, it deals with fields separated by some separator - when I need to remove (and write to file) any regexp-matching substrings. Sorry, it appears my example was horribly misleading (may be it was better without one).

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    split($0,flds,re,seps)
    for (i=1;i in flds;i++) {
        printf "%s", flds[i]
        if (i in seps)
            print seps[i] > "removed.txt"
    }
    print ""
}

$ echo -e " apple pears banana \n kiwi ananas cocoa" | awk -v re=' [ab][a-z]+' -f tst.awk
 pears
 kiwi cocoa

$ cat removed.txt
 apple
 banana
 ananas
```